# Add timestamp to JSON php output

Tags: json, timestamp

I have a bitcoin miner (running linux), and by php querying it returns a JSON string as follows

```
{"CG_Uptime":753991,"MHS_Avg":3587198.92,"DegC_In":"27","DegC_TopOut":"58","DegC_BotOut":"67"}
```

(shortened it to keep it simple).

What I want is to make a cron job that gets this data every a specified time period, adds a timestamp, produce another JSON string with timestamp added and append to a json log file that includes this data per timestamp.
In example, my log file would be something like

```
{"Data": {
 "Data1":{"Year":"2015","Month":"05","Day":"01","Hour":"23","Minutes":"20","Seconds":"30","Stats":{"CG_Uptime":753991,"MHS_Avg":3587198.92,"DegC_In":"27","DegC_TopOut":"58","DegC_BotOut":"67"}},
  "Data2":{"Year":"2015","Month":"05","Day":"02","Hour":"23","Minutes":"20","Seconds":"30","Stats":{"CG_Uptime":753991,"MHS_Avg":3587198.92,"DegC_In":"27","DegC_TopOut":"58","DegC_BotOut":"67"}},
  "Data3":{"Year":"2015","Month":"05","Day":"03","Hour":"23","Minutes":"20","Seconds":"30","Stats":{"CG_Uptime":753991,"MHS_Avg":3587198.92,"DegC_In":"27","DegC_TopOut":"58","DegC_BotOut":"67"}}}}
```

etc.

Can someone help me on how to do this?
I'd prefer to implement this in PHP.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet

Answer (score 0):

Use json_encode  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php as a starting point

gist of code to start

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'Year' => date(Y),
'Month' => date(M));

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

will give you {"Year":"2015","Month":"May"}.

if you will provide source of the input I can help you finish it